# ssh-keygen -R server_name - удаляет информацию о ключах с локального ПК или с сервера тоже?

Tags: ssh, ssh-key

```
$ ssh-keygen -R server_name
# удаляет информацию о ключах с локального ПК или с сервера тоже?
```

В мануале:

> -R
>
> 1. Удаляет все ключи, принадлежащие к имени хоста, из файла known_hosts.
> 2. Этот параметр полезен для удаления хешированных хостов.

Здесь же имеется ввиду **локальный файл** `~/.ssh/known_hosts` а не файл сервера, я прав? Если да то как сервер узнает, что я удалил свой приватный ключ, например если он скомпрометирован? (просто нужно понять).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Здесь же имеется ввиду **локальный файл** `~/.ssh/known_hosts` а не файл сервера, я прав?

Да. Только с вашим ключом это никак не связано. Там хранится отпечаток ключа **сервера**; чтобы можно было увидеть подмену удалённого узла. При первом соединении с сервером, если замечали, `ssh` просит подтвердить отпечаток. При последующих соединениях проверяется, что отпечаток прежний; и если приходит другой, поднимается **тревога**.

> Если да то как сервер узнает, что я удалил свой приватный ключ...

Никак. Он не знает о том, где ключ может существовать. У него в списке разрешённых публичных ключей (обычно в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` **на сервере** у пользователя, за которого совершается вход).

> ...например если он скомпрометирован?

В этом случае соответствующий публичный ключ необходимо убрать с сервера из вышеупомянутого файла.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Здесь же имеется ввиду локальный файл ~/.ssh/known_hosts а не файл сервера, я прав? Если да то как сервер узнает, что я удалил свой приватный ключ, например если он скомпрометирован? (просто нужно понять)

1. ваш секретный ключ никак не пересекается с содержимым `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (этот файл нужен для обнаружения факта подмены удалённого сервера, и содержит «отпечатки»/fingerprints/хэши секретных ключей **серверов**).
2. о том, что вы удалили свой секретный ключ, сервер, действительно, никогда не узнает. ведь этот секретный ключ (точнее, его «отпечаток», *fingerprint*, хэш) больше не будет упоминаться вашим ssh-клиентом на стадии подключения, когда клиент и сервер согласовывают, с какой именно парой ключей (точнее — пара из секретной и публичной частей ключа) будет происходить аутентификация (ведь ssh-клиенту может быть доступно множество секретных ключей, а ssh-серверу может быть доступно множество публичных ключей, с которыми разрешено проводить аутентификацию данного пользователя).